# TypeScript: why isn't `Function` assignable to `(...args: any[]) => any`?

Tags: typescript

```
declare var a: (...args: any[]) => any;
declare var b: Function;
a = b;

// Error:
// Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => any'.
//  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): any'
```

Even though it's almost never a good idea to use the type `Function`, I want the type definitions I write to be compatible with this type. In particular, when `Function` is passed to a generic function:

```
declare function foo<T>(bar: (...args: any[]) => T): T;
declare var baz: Function;
foo(baz);
```

It fails with the same error whereas it seems reasonable to expect it to work and to infer `T` to be `any`

Comment: In your example `a` is more specific than `b`. So it makes sense that you cannot assign `b` to the more specific `a`. If you want to force the types to be compatible, use type assertions (`as`).

Comment: I can't see how it's more specific. `Function` can be also called with `new`. So `Function` should be the same thing as `((...args: any[]) => any) & (new (...args: any[]) => object)`. And we *can* assign this type to `(...args: any[]) => T`. But not `Function`. Why?

Comment: Note that we can assign any other function type to `a`. E.g. `(x: number) => void`, even `(x: number) => never` works.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following:

```
interface FunctionWithTypedReturn<T> extends Function {
    (...args: any[]): T;
}

declare function foo<T>(bar: FunctionWithTypedReturn<T>): T;

declare var baz: FunctionWithTypedReturn<number>;

foo(baz);
```

Comment: But why doesn't `Function` work like this out of the box? Why is there a difference between `((...args: any[]) => any) & (new (...args: any[]) => object)` and `Function`? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the answer :( you can see that [the declaration of `Function` says nothing about arguments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L250-L282).